# Change input placeholder color from the Chrome Developer Tools style

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I did an `input` with blue font color and red `placeholder` ,

now I want to check other `placeholder` colors by the Chrome Developer Tools (F12) , as same as I can do for the font color  -

[image]

how could I get the same Chrome Developer Tools color picker for the `placeholder` as well ?

```css
input[type="text"] {
    color: blue;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Type Here">
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understood you well, you want to have color picker in Chrome Developer Tool, the same like for font. To do it, follow steps:

1. Press F12
2. Click `+` icon in the top right corner of the right sidebar:
   [image]
3. Add new rule. Paste your selector and your properties:
   [image]

Now you can modify your rule in the same way as for font color. I hope this is what you want to achieve

Comment: Exactly what I wanted . Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

To see and manipulate the `::placeholder` styles in Chrome devtools you can enable the `Show user agent shadow DOM` setting. It can be found in the devtools settings under **⚙️ > Preferences > Elements**.

I found the solution in this blogpost: https://newbedev.com/inspect-webkit-input-placeholder-with-developer-tools

Greetings from 2021